# Google Apps Script parse .txt file and insert content to a sheet?

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, google-apps-script

I was wondering; the same way that I can parse .CSV file and insert data to google sheet, is this possible for a .txt file? How could I manage to do this? Below is the code how this works with .CSV file, but I cannot find a way to make it work with a .txt -file. What would be the best approach to do this for a .txt file?

```js
function importCSV() {
  var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv";
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));
  var sheetName = writeDataToSheet(contents);
}

function writeDataToSheet(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}
```

Comment: Does your text file have any separators that would allow you to parse the data correctly? E.g. commas between column entries?

Comment: Yes it does, commas

Comment: If it is separated by commas, how is it different compared to a CSV? Do you have a sample of the file to share?

Comment: In what way(s) does your file not have CSV content?

Comment: Hey! It seems like it works only for .txt -files without commas, with commas, I get the following error: Exception: Could not parse text.

Answer (score 0):

Try Utilities.parseCsv() on your text file.

Comment: Hey! It seems like it works only for .txt -files without commas, with commas, I get the following error: Exception: Could not parse text.

Comment: Specify a delimiter: [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter).